# Adding new view to Dexterity type causes "page not found" viewing items

Tags: templates, plone, dexterity

I'm working through the recent Professional Plone 4 Development book, on a Plone 4.1.2 install.

I have successfully defined the content types via Dexterity and am now trying to create a custom view for one of the types. The schema & view are defined as such:

```
from zope import schema
from plone.directives import form
from five import grok
from ctcc.contenttypes import CTCCTypesMessageFactory as _

class ITrial(form.Schema):
    """A clinical trial."""

    title = schema.TextLine(
        title = _(u'label_title', default=u'Title'),
        required = True,
    )

    description = schema.Text(
        title=_(u'label_description', default=u'Description'),
        description = _(u'help_description', default=u'A short summary of the content'),
        required = False,
        missing_value = u'',
    )

class View(grok.View):
    grok.context(ITrial)
    grok.require('zope2.View')
    grok.name('view')
```

Here is the relevant section from the type's FTI:
    view
    False

```
<alias from="(Default)" to="(selected layout)"/>
<alias from="edit" to="@@edit"/>
<alias from="sharing" to="@@sharing"/>
<alias from="view" to="@@view"/>

<action title="View" action_id="view" category="object" condition_expr=""
    url_expr="string:${folder_url}/" visible="True">
    <permission value="View"/>
</action>
```

And the template itself, located in **ctcc.contenttypes/trial_templates/view.pt**, which should simply display the title & description:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
      lang="en"
      metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
      i18n:domain="ctcc.contenttypes">
<body>

<metal:content-core fill-slot="content-core">
    <metal:content-core define-macro="content-core">

        <div tal:replace="structure context/text/output" />

    </metal:content-core>
</metal:content-core>

</body>
</html>
```

Accessing any instances of the type with all this in place causes a "page not found" error. Something doesn't seem to be tying up the new view to the expected path, but as this is my first week with Plone I've no idea where to begin to track this down. I'm seeing no errors running the site in foreground mode either.

Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that you should rerun the appropriate step in portal_setup after you've changed something in the GenericSetup XML?

Comment: Go to error_log in the ZMI and remove NotFound from the list of ignored exceptions. Then go to the view again and see if you get any more information.

Comment: @JC Brand: At this stage I'm not modifying any GenericSetup files at all. The dexterity type has been created and works fine, it's only after adding the view in the python file that it starts giving the error. 

Thank you, though, I really should have made that more clear and will update now.

Comment: @David Glick: Thank you, that not only helped expose the problem that's an invaluable debugging tip in its own right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line in the template:

```
<div tal:replace="structure context/text/output" />
```

I had stripped back an example template to what I *thought* was the bare minimum. Thanks to David Glick's suggestion, I removed **NotFound** from the ignored exceptions list in **error_log** and saw the following:

```
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 225, in evaluateText
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /opt/plone41/zeocluster/src/ctcc.contenttypes/ctcc/contenttypes/trial_templates/view.pt
   - Line 13, Column 8
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'context/text/output'>
  [...]
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 299, in unrestrictedTraverse
   - __traceback_info__: ([], 'text')
NotFound: text
```

Now that I can see what's causing the problem and have started reading deeper into TALs, I can see why it's failing: ignorance on my behalf, as suspected.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

did you included the dependency in setup.py?

```
install_requires=[
  'setuptools',
  'plone.app.dexterity',
  ...
  ],
```

did you initialized Grok in your configure.zcml?

```
<configure
  xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
  ...
  xmlns:grok="http://namespaces.zope.org/grok">

  <includeDependencies package="." />
  <grok:grok package="." />
  ...

</configure>
```

did you included Dexterity's GenericSetup profile in your metadata.xml?

```
<metadata>
 <version>1</version>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>profile-plone.app.dexterity:default</dependency>
 </dependencies>
</metadata>
```

Comment: All of those were as specified, although my setup.py has 'plone.app.dexterity [grok]' instead. I should have specified in the question that the basic type creation functionality was working fine, it was only custom views on those types that failed. Thank you for your help anyway.